# Azure OS disk memory issue

Tags: azure, ubuntu-16.04, azure-virtual-machine

I have created a virtual machine on Azure and tried to increase the size of the OS disk to 50 GB in the Microsoft Azure portal. I was able to increase the size and could see it increased in the Azure portal. But it is not getting reflected in the virtual machine. To check the size I have used the command
'**df -h**'.

Refer to the following screenshots for the azure portal and the virtual machine.
This image refers to the disk size in the azure UI[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a2xFQ.png).
This image refers to the OS disk size in the virtual machine, which is not reflected.[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/taPMu.png)

Answer (score 0):

Azure managed disks automatically encrypt your data by default when persisting it to the cloud. From your screenshot, the disk has not encryption. You could verify if the disk is OS disk or data disk or other unmanaged disk.

If the Azure VM has a GPT partition in Linux (run `sudo parted -l /dev/sda` to identify whether the OS disk has an MBR or GPT partition), you can follow these steps to [increase the size of the OS disk](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/resize-os-disk-gpt-partition#increase-the-size-of-the-os-disk) in Ubuntu 16.x and 18.x:

[image]

In this case, you could log in to the VM as a root user and check it again. Furthermore, you may need to resize the partition refer to  https://lnx.azurewebsites.net/resizing-a-linux-vm-system-disk-in-microsoft-azure/

For me, to increase the size of the OS disk to 50 GB from Azure portal
[image]

SSH to the Azure VM and check it.

[image]